# How do you export a 3d-model in QGIS to a file that can be read in Rhino?

Tags: qgis, export, 3d, terrain

I am really new to QGIS and haven't really gotten familiar with all the functions yet. I've made a 3D map/model in QGIS, and would like to export this in a file format so that I can use it as a terrain model in Rhino. How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have to export the 3D view. This is just a visualisation. The source data is what you want to be looking at. Am guessing that your source data is going to be a Digital Elevation Model (DEM) or TIN. Possibly a raster gridded dataset might be suitable also.
All of this will of course depend on what Rhino can support as an input file.
The question might be more suited to being a 'What GIS formats does Rhino software accept as input"